# Error: Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'NSUInteger' is not an integral or objective c pointer type

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array named "rankStrings" and I am trying to get the data from it at an index as below...

```
NSArray *rankStrings = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10"];

return [rankStrings[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
```

the "rank" is declared as...

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger *rank;
```

I get error, "Indexing expression is invalid because subscript type 'NSUInteger' is not an integral or objective c pointer type".

I tried using "NSInteger" or "int" instead of "NSUInteger", but it is still the same.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using a **pointer** to a `NSUInteger`, and the array expects a `NSUInteger` (primitive type) as index. Declare your property like this instead:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSUInteger rank;
```

Comment: Yeah, You are right. That was the problem. Thank you very much!!