# Unable to insert into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

This is how I initialize it:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, UIImage *> *images;
```

This is how I insert:

```
NSString *stringDate = [self getddMMyyyyInString:firstDate]

[[self.images setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rsz_fill.png"] forKey:stringDate]];
```

The error that I got is

> indexing expression is invalid because subscript type void is not an
>   integral or objective c pointer type

How can I insert `NSString` and `UIImage` into the `NSmutabledictionary`?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `stringDate`

Comment: @SPUDERMAN Did you alloc your images Dictionary?

Comment: Make sure your `getddMMyyyyInString` returns a fixed format.

Comment: @Imad you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, UIImage *> *images;


self.images = [NSMutableDictionary new];

NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rsz_fill.png"];

[self.images setObject:image forKey:stringDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when primitive type is expected, but a pointer is provided.

Below code is working fine for me. Try it.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, UIImage *> *images;

//inside some method (say viewDidLoad)

NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];

[self.images setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forKey:stringDate];
```

Also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928930/error-indexing-expression-is-invalid-because-subscript-type-nsuinteger-is-not)

Comment: Also, try removing those extra square brackets ([self.images setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rsz_fill.png"] forKey:stringDate]). At times, issue is different and error thrown is different.